# What can I say about the combination of analytic functions with infinite radius of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are real-analytic functions, such that their **Taylor Series** around $x_0$ have an infinite radius of convergence:

$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^kf(x_0)}{dx^k}(x-x_0)^k \;\;,\;\forall x\in \Bbb R $

$g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^kg(x_0)}{dx^k}(x-x_0)^k \;\;,\;\forall x\in \Bbb R $

---

If I have a combination of those functions, such that:

$h(x) = \alpha\,f(x) + \beta\,g(x) + \gamma\,f(x)\,g(x)\;\;,\;(\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb R)$

Is $h(x)$ analytic? Moreover, its radius of convergence around $x_0$, is it infinite?

---

What if: $h(x) =\frac{1}{f(x)}$

Comment: Yes, of course. Your assumptions mean that all your series converge uniformly and absolutely in closed finite intervals, so you can perform all those linear combinations/multiplications, and the resulting series converge, in every finite interval. So their radius of convergence is infinite, too.

Comment: $f(x)g(x)$ requires a special treatment : $$g(x)f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^kg(x_0)}{dx^k}(x-x_0)^k  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\frac{d^nf(x_0)}{dx^n}(x-x_0)^n =  \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (x-x_0)^m (\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^kf(x_0)}{dx^k} \frac{1}{(m-k)!}\frac{d^{m-k}g(x_0)}{dx^{m-k}})$$ thus $g(x)f(x)$ is an everywhere convergent power series so by definition it is analytic

Comment: How about division? $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ would have a finite radius of convergence? Would it be the distance between $x_0$ and the nearest root of $f(x)$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Even if $f$ has no real roots, $1/f$ may still have a shortened radius of convergence because of complex roots. Consider $f(x)=x^2+1$.

Comment: Well, would it be then the distance between $x_0$ and the nearest complex root?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$